# Update value in field where value falls at certain index in string

Tags: mysql, sql

I dont think this one has been asked before, but correct me if I am wrong.

I have a field name, lets say `'field'`. it contains a space separated list of 10 2 digit number:

`0 0 0 1 12 7 -1 6 9 15`

I want to update the field to replace any -1 value with a 0 if it is the 4th, 5th, 6th or 7th number.

This cannot be done with `charindex` as the 2 digit numbers are sometimes single digit if they are under 10 (shown above). The only way to differentiate between a new number is the space delimitation.

Any ideas if this is even possible and how I might do it?

Thanks.

Comment: This not how you should use a DB. store every single value seperately

Comment: agreed, working with a legacy system however. gotta work with what iv got unfortunately.

Comment: Then I would insist on changing it.

Comment: not feesable in this case unfortunately

Comment: I don't think SQL is really built for this kind of thing.  I don't know how to do this in SQL, but I have a feeling it's possible.  My only suggestion is to just fetch the data and process it off-server and update.

Comment: I went down the same trail of thought. I can do this by running a PHP script that grabs the data, converts the strings it needs to and then updates them, but I am sure this is possible in SQL alone which would save me a whole load of deploy headaches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this:

```
select concat_ws(' ', substring_index(field, ' ', 3),
                 replace(substring_index(substring_index(field, ' ', 7), ' ', -4), -1, 0),
                 substring_index(field, ' ', -3)
                )
```

This splits the list into three parts -- the first three elements, the middle four, and the last three.  The `replace()` is done only on the middle four.

Then you should fix the data structure to use a junction table.

Comment: this seems like a much easier way of doing it than the above, however the result removes the space between the 3rd & 4th number and the 7th & 8th numbers. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: @MikeOram . . . Yes.  The easiest way is to use `concat_ws()` (I just fixed the answer).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't fully tested. I would probably run this and spot check a few to make sure you get the desired results. Converting it to an update is simple enough. Or you could write it to a temp table and then join it back and update. I prefer the latter because at least you know which ones you changed and what they were prior.

The logic is pretty simple. Get the first 3 numbers. Determine if the 4th number is -1 or 2 digits/characters. I had to do this to get the spacing right. Get the 5th and 6th number. Determine if the 7th number is -1 or 2 digits/characters. Get the 8th, 9th, 10th numbers.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc521c/1)**

```
SELECT 
  field,
  CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ' ', 3),
  CASE 
    WHEN RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,' ',4), 2) = '-1' THEN ' 0'
    WHEN RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,' ',4), 2) LIKE ' %' THEN RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,' ',4), 2)
    ELSE RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,' ',4), 3)
  END,
  CONCAT(' ',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ' ',6), ' ', -2)),
  CASE 
    WHEN RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,' ',7), 2) = '-1' THEN ' 0'
    WHEN RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,' ',7), 2) LIKE ' %' THEN RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,' ',4), 1)     
    ELSE RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,' ',7), 3)
  END,
  CONCAT(' ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ' ', -3))) as 'newField'
FROM YourTable
WHERE RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,' ',4), 2) = '-1'
  OR RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,' ',7), 2) = '-1';
```

Comment: this is very almost what I need, however I think maybe my question was not clear enough, the -1 to 0 replace needs to happen on the 4th 5th 6th and 7th number, not the 4th and 7th only.

Comment: iv updated your query to select all the values needed, how do I make it to an update rather than a select?

Comment: `update YourTable set field = CONCAT(substring..........)` Like I said though. I would create a temp table with the values first or at least make a backup so you can quickly revert back if there is some unintended effects.

Comment: Gordon's answer is the way to go. For some reason I had it in my mind that MySQL didn't have replace hence my case statements.